# Relaciones con tabla pivot o dinámica

Tags: laravel-7

Requiero hacer la relación entre Categories, Products y Attribute_Products en este caso mi tabla pivot o dinámica es Attribute_Products, la relación entre Categories y Products la hago con belongsToMany:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('name','products');
    }

    public function Attribute_Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('id','attributes_products',
            '','');
    }

class Product extends Model
{
    public function Categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('id','categories','');
    }

    public function Attribute_Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('id','attributes_products');
    }
}
```

Pero cuando hago la relación con mi tabla pivot Attribute_Products, no estoy seguro de si crear el modelo usar la relaciones Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns hay si estoy perdido.
Diagrama de base de datos:

[image: Diagrama de base de datos]

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, pero claro que la requiero en este caso es una db de un ecommerce, dado el caso que se seleccione una categoría, se debe traer los productos y por ende si yo selecciono un producto este me debería traer sus atributos ejemplo: si mi categoría es Componentes y mi producto es una Ram debo mostrar sus atributos como Marca, Capacidad, Tipo de Memoria y su capacidad

Comment: Tienes razón en este caso mi tabla intermedia o bien mi modelo no sería Attribute si lo pienso bien es en realidad Attributes_Products

Comment: Si, en realidad debo crear el modelo, pero no quede claro  con Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns, ya que trae poco info la doc. Igual gracias por los comentarios!

Comment: Pero si yo tengo un atributo que sea socket, debería de tener un soket para laptops, tarjetas madres o igual si tengo un atributo que sea waltage, tendría que tener waltage para memorias ram, para fuentes de poder  eso es lo que me quiero evitar

Comment: Porque dices que tendría un fallo?

Comment: Logre resolverlo te invito a verlo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre Resolverlo de esta manera para mis tablas principales: Categories, Products las relaciones serian las siguientes:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Products(){
        return $this->hasMany('name','products');
    }

    public function Attributes_Products(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function Categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('id','categories','');
    }

    public function Attributes_Products(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Y para mi tabla intermedia me quedo:

```
class Attribute_Products extends Model
{
    public function Products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_id','id');
    }

    public function Categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_id', 'id');
    }
    public function Attributes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'attribute', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente (*después de revisar de nuevo el contexto de tu pregunta*)

1. Las relaciones *belongsToMany* las debes declarar en los modelos que están vinculados a tu tabla *pivot* la cual en este caso sería: `Attribute_Products`

Entonces en el modelo *Category* debería existir un método similar a esto:

```
public function Products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Luego en el modelo *Product* la siguiente relación:

```
public function Categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

2. Al respecto de tu tabla *Attribute*

La misma (**y debo recalcar que esto es solo mi forma de entender**) no debería o no tendría razón de existir, pues según los comentarios son atributos propios de cada producto que se va registrando, entonces deberían estar como parte de la tabla productos y no por fuera de ella, ya que si revisamos tu entidad productos la misma esta muy incompleta.

Entonces después de lo anterior:

- Considero que el mayor problema radica en la normalización de tu base de datos
- Las relaciones que propones en tu respuesta de hecho no terminan de ajustarse del todo a las relaciones que vemos entre tus tablas en la imagen que compartes
- Si la tabla pivot se alimenta al final de product y de category, entonces su nombre debe reflejar a estas 2 entidades
- Una vez que tuvieras claros esos puntos, será mucho mas fácil trasladar todo ese contexto a Eloquent